# CSS - Element overflowing/overlapping this parent div while still staying overflow:hidden;?

Tags: html, css, position, overflow, css-position

Here is my mockup (=design) what I want to achieve in code.

- As you can see the `<h1>Happy Fruit</h1>` is **overlapping** the **parent** `div .slider`
- Also on the bottom you can see that the `.slider_dots` (the slider navigation bottom) is also **overlapping** the parent `div .slider`

**By parent div** I mean that both the `<h1>` and `.slider_dots` are nested inside the `div .slider`

[image: mockup]

Okay so here is the tricky part, I know I can easily fix this by using `.slider { overflow: visible; }` **then the text will overlap the parent** `div .slider` but when **I do this I get that you can see the other slides next to it** (like u can see on the img below). Because it's a slider it needs to be `.slider { overflow: hidden; }`

[image: overflow: visible;]

`.slider { overflow: hidden; }` and then giving a negative value to the  (pushing it up). It just **dissapears** inside the parent `div .slider` like so.

[image]

Anyone knows how I can do a workaround this? I tried working with `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` but they don't seem to work.

**I've uploaded a live version** [here on my hosting](http://lucasdebelder.be/test/index.html) (third page) incase you want to play/try something. I can upload it to a jsfiddle if needed as well although it's a ton of code.

(If the text is strike-through that means you are viewing it on a bad viewport, try dragging your window down it's only now written for phone/tablet size.)

[Slider used.](https://codepen.io/electerious/pen/JXNEPr)

Comment: @VictorAllegret Thanks for the reply, I've tried that but it doesn't work and I think it's because of this problem http://i.imgur.com/XKVNXAU.jpg as you can see the <h1> is longer then the div but I can't figure out why

Comment: 1) Add code of your slider. 2) You can avoid `overflow: hidden` pain by placing elements using position absolute and using `z-index` to hide then. By the way you can add some `active` class for current element and hide `h1` when element doesn't have `active` class.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov I have used this slider https://codepen.io/electerious/pen/JXNEPr only the design is adjusted

Comment: @Panic Edit your answer and add this code.

Comment: @Panic Why can't you just apply solution with gradient and pseudoelement?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Thanks for the help, I've tried that but it didn't really work :(

Comment: @Panic Where is code of what you've tried? And why do you think it is legal to ask the same question for the third time?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add another inner element to your slider. That way, you can pad it at the top, and apply your background. You can then pull your content back up, overlapping the background. That way you can apply your overflow as usual, whilst also no longer cropping the text.